# Azure Pipeline E2E Testing: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: node.js, angular, azure-devops, protractor, e2e-testing

I about to run my protractor test in azure pipeline.
Following steps are success,

1. npm install
2. webdriver update

when running "npm run e2e" got below error (highlighted with space),

```
2020-12-28T11:24:00.1123719Z Date: 2020-12-28T11:24:00.108Z - Hash: 3bfb7dbf8249d8ecd0a9 - Time: 44081ms
2020-12-28T11:24:00.1205386Z ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4203, open your browser on http://localhost:4203/ **
2020-12-28T11:24:00.1739298Z [34mâ„¹[39m [90mï½¢wdmï½£[39m: Compiled successfully.
2020-12-28T11:24:01.9754480Z [11:24:01] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
2020-12-28T11:24:01.9755656Z [11:24:01] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...


2020-12-28T11:24:06.7970214Z [11:24:06] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7972134Z   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7980054Z   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)



2020-12-28T11:24:06.7981720Z   (Driver info: chromedriver=87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c3464b5dd1302349b1382549290d-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#1761}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-1100-azure x86_64)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7982724Z [11:24:06] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7983474Z   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7984515Z   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7985577Z   (Driver info: chromedriver=87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c3464b5dd1302349b1382549290d-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#1761}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-1100-azure x86_64)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7986586Z     at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/vsts/work/1/s/amaze-commerce/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7987489Z     at parseHttpResponse (/home/vsts/work/1/s/amaze-commerce/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7988405Z     at doSend.then.response (/home/vsts/work/1/s/amaze-commerce/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7988962Z     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7989391Z From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7990163Z     at Function.createSession (/home/vsts/work/1/s/amaze-commerce/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7991076Z     at Function.createSession (/home/vsts/work/1/s/amaze-commerce/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7992017Z     at Direct.getNewDriver (/home/vsts/work/1/s/amaze-commerce/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7992916Z     at Runner.createBrowser (/home/vsts/work/1/s/amaze-commerce/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.7993802Z     at q.then.then (/home/vsts/work/1/s/amaze-commerce/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.8001078Z     at _fulfilled (/home/vsts/work/1/s/amaze-commerce/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.8001877Z     at /home/vsts/work/1/s/amaze-commerce/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
2020-12-28T11:24:06.8002782Z     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/vsts/work/1/s/amaze-commerce/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.8003556Z     at /home/vsts/work/1/s/amaze-commerce/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
2020-12-28T11:24:06.8004307Z     at runSingle (/home/vsts/work/1/s/amaze-commerce/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
2020-12-28T11:24:06.8005078Z [11:24:06] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
2020-12-28T11:24:07.4394944Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-12-28T11:24:07.4395828Z npm ERR! errno 1
2020-12-28T11:24:07.4462731Z npm ERR! amaze-commerce@1.0.0 e2etest: `node --max_old_space_size=35000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng e2e`
2020-12-28T11:24:07.4465097Z npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-12-28T11:24:07.4468705Z npm ERR! 
2020-12-28T11:24:07.4472803Z npm ERR! Failed at the amaze-commerce@1.0.0 e2etest script.
2020-12-28T11:24:07.4475619Z npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-12-28T11:24:07.4546066Z 
2020-12-28T11:24:07.4546683Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-12-28T11:24:07.4547625Z npm ERR!     /home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2020-12-28T11_24_07_448Z-debug.log
2020-12-28T11:24:07.4656714Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
2020-12-28T11:24:07.4737893Z ##[section]Finishing: run e2e test
```

[image]
Please help me on this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When you run "npm run e2e" locally, how's the result? Which agent pool do you use? You may set system.debug variable to true and check whether there is more detailed log.

Comment: Locally no problem, it is running successfully.

Comment: Which agent pool do you use? Have you tried setting system.debug variable to true? Are you able to get more detailed log?

Answer (score 1):

Add below chromeOptions in protractor.conf file

```
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox','--headless', '--disable-extensions', '--disable-dev-shm-usage']
    }
```

--disable-dev-shm-usage :  overcome limited resource problems

```
// The /dev/shm partition is too small in certain VM environments, causing
// Chrome to fail or crash (see http://crbug.com/715363). Use disable-dev-shm-usage flag to
// work-around this issue (a temporary directory will always be used to create
// anonymous shared memory files).
```

Comment: the same is added, still no changes in the issue.